# Doesn't the second postulate of special relativity imply the existence of "luminiferous ether"?

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, aether

Einstein expressed his Second Postulate in *[On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/www/)* as:

> light is always propagated in empty space with a definite velocity $c$ which is independent of the state of motion of the emitting body.

and

> Any ray of light moves in the “stationary” system of co-ordinates with the determined velocity $c$, whether the ray be emitted by a stationary or by a moving body.

Since this is also true for sound propagating in air, doesn't the Second Postulate of Relativity imply light propagates through a medium, e.g., "luminiferous ether"?

However, Einstein continues:

> The introduction of a “luminiferous ether” will prove to be superfluous inasmuch as the view here to be developed will not require an “absolutely stationary space” provided with special properties, nor assign a velocity-vector to a point of the empty space in which electromagnetic processes take place.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What logical link do you *think* exists? If A has properties P and Q, and B also has property P, that doesn't imply that B has property Q.

Comment: @BenCrowell: ¿Aren't these statements true: "_sound is always propagated in air with a definite velocity $v_\mathrm{sound}$ which is independent of the state of motion of the emitting body._" and "_Any sound wave moves in the 'stationary' system of co-ordinates with the determined velocity $v_\mathrm{sound}$, whether the wave be emitted by a stationary or by a moving body._" (All I did is substitute: light→sound, $c$→$v_\mathrm{sound}$, and "empty space"→"air".)

Comment: @Geremia Both those statements are true if modified to read "with a definite velocity c *in the rest frame of the medium*", but for light the first is true without such modification (it applies to *all* inertial observers) and the second presumes the existence of a absolute rest which does not exist.

Comment: dmckee is right, and to add to that answer, if $ v_{sound} $ is the speed of sound as measured in the rest frame of the atmosphere (or some other medium), then the speed of a sound wave will *not* be equal to $ v_{sound} $ in an inertial frame that's moving relative to the rest frame of the atmosphere. Whereas the 2nd postulate of relativity is saying you can pick *any* inertial frame as the one you call "stationary", and you'll always find that light waves move at c relative to this "stationary" frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since this is also true for sound propagating in air

No, actually, it isn't.  There's something crucial that you've left out.  Look more closely at the 2nd postulate:

> light is always propagated in empty space with a definite velocity c
>   which is independent of the state of motion of the emitting body.

Now, this holds *for the emitter of the light too*.  Do you see this?

According to the emitting body, the light it emits propagates with speed $c$ *regardless*.

But this clearly doesn't hold in the case of sound when the emitter is moving with respect to the medium; the sound emitter in relative motion with the medium finds that the speed with which the emitted sound waves propagate depends on the relative speed of the emitter and medium.

Comment: Huh? The speed of propagation of sound *is* independent of the speed of the emitter.

Comment: @BenCrowell, not according to the emitter that is moving in the medium.

Comment: @Ben Crowell - I think the point is that different emitters won't all measure the same speed of sound in their *own* frames--emitters with different speeds relative to the rest frame of the medium will measure different speeds for sound waves in their own rest frames. When people say the speed is independent of the emitter, what they mean is that once you choose a particular frame, then the speed of a sound wave in any direction (it may be different in different directions if the frame is not the rest frame of the medium) is independent of the speed of the emitter relative to that frame.

Comment: ...whereas of course relativity's 2nd postulate says that every inertial emitter must measure a light wave to move at c in that emitter's own inertial rest frame.